# Javascript detect if not pressing a certain key

Tags: javascript

Ok, so I have a simple program that changes the walking animation when the character is walking (This is obviously not the full program):

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {

    if (event.keyCode == 37) { //left arrow
        walkSound.play();
        playerXPos -= playerSpeed;
        if (currentSkin == playerWalkSkins.length-1) {
            currentSkin = 0;
        }
        else {
            currentSkin++;
        }
    }

    else if (event.keyCode == 39) { //right arrow
        walkSound.play();
        playerXPos += playerSpeed;
        if (currentSkin == playerWalkSkins.length-1) {
            currentSkin = 0;
        }
        else {
            currentSkin++;
        }
    }
}, false);
```

However, I want some code that makes the animation go to a different skin when the character is not walking.

In psudocode, here is basically what I want:

```
if (pressing left or right key) {
    //animate walking
}     
else {
    //stand still img
}
```

Thank you so much to anyone who can help me!

Comment: You can use the `onkeyup` event in conjuction with the `onkeydown` event to keep track of pressed keys.

Comment: so put in some keyup handlers and change to that skin when neither 37 or 39 is down.

Comment: You can use a `Timer`

Comment: @Halcyon That sounds legit, but I never found that on online tutorials. I'll check again, and if it works, you should post it as an answer so I could accept you!

Comment: ` if (event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39){// walking} else{//stand}`

Comment: @Demandooda JavaScript tutorials are notoriously bad, usually there is a lot of missing information. There's only a couple of sites that I really trust, the major one is MDN's JavaScript section. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: @Azzi I tried that, but I don't know if else works for event listeners.

Comment: @Azzi that doesn't work. Let's say I press and hold `left arrow` and then I press `a`, the character would stop but I'm still holding `left arrow`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in many comments, `keyup` is your friend here. Some code to make it easy for you (credits to @Halcyon though):

```
var keyleft = False;
var keyright = False;

document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {

    if (event.keyCode == 37) { //left arrow
        walkSound.play();
        keyleft = True;
        playerXPos -= playerSpeed;
        if (currentSkin == playerWalkSkins.length-1) {
            currentSkin = 0;
        }
        else {
            currentSkin++;
        }
    }

    else if (event.keyCode == 39) { //right arrow
        walkSound.play();
        keyright= True;
        playerXPos += playerSpeed;
        if (currentSkin == playerWalkSkins.length-1) {
            currentSkin = 0;
        }
        else {
            currentSkin++;
        }
    }
}, false);

document.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {

    if (event.keyCode == 37) { //left arrow
        keyleft = False;
    }

    else if (event.keyCode == 39) { //right arrow
        keyright= False;     
    }
    if (keyleft==False && keyright==False){
        //your code here
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Ill try that. Thnak you for giving a detailed answer!

Comment: Your welcome, let me know if it works. I typed it on mobile so be careful for typos (I don't see any but just in case)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onkeyup` event in conjuction with the `onkeydown` event to keep track of pressed keys.

Based on Bas' answer, here is a more complete code example:

```
var left_key_pressed = false;
var right_key_pressed = false;

document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 37) { //left arrow
        left_key_pressed = true;
        update_walking_state();
    } else if (event.keyCode == 39) { //right arrow
        right_key_pressed = true;
        update_walking_state();
    }
}, false);

document.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {

    if (event.keyCode == 37) { //left arrow
        left_key_pressed = false;
        update_walking_state();
    } else if (event.keyCode == 39) { //right arrow
        right_key_pressed = false;
        update_walking_state();
    }
}, false);

function update_walking_state() {
    if (left_key_pressed) {
        // walk left
    } else if (right_key_pressed) {
        // walk right
    } else {
        // hammer time
    }
}

function ticker() {
    if (left_key_pressed) {
        walkSound.play();
        playerXPos -= playerSpeed;
    } else if (right_key_pressed) {
        walkSound.play();
        playerXPos += playerSpeed;
    }
}

setInterval(ticker, 100); // run every 100ms
```

Comment: If your accept is deleyed, it means I am doing research into this onkeyup that I did nto know about. THx!

Comment: Don't worry about it. If you have any other question feel free to ask.

Comment: Wait, I checked w3 schools and it said that onkeyup is in html. Is there a way I could make it part of my js code?

Comment: See my updated answer. I added the `update_walking_state` function and a ticker that will keep moving player (and play sounds) as the keys are held. You could move `update_walking_state()` to the ticker as well.